# Showing that the radius of convergence of a power series is $R=\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Let $a_k,z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $A(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_kz^k$ with
>   radius of convergence  $R$.
>
> For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 \le x < R$, $A(x) = e^x
> > -2e^{-2x}$.
>
> 1. prove $R=\infty$
> 2. find $A(i\pi)$

My attempt was to use $A(x)$ with Taylor expansion, but it didn't really help me much. How should I attack this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that the power series for $e^z=\sum z^n/n!$ converges everywhere. For the computation, use the Hadamard formula:  $r=1/\limsup1/\sqrt[n]{n!}=1/1/\infty=1/0=\infty$.

By the identity theorem, $A(z)=e^z-2e^{-2z}$.

It follows that $A(i\pi)=e^{i\pi}-2e^{-2i\pi}=-1-2=-3$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Taylor series of exp :
$$e^z=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$
Next step you calculate $A(x)$ using this series and you will have what you want.

Comment: so basically i can say: $A(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} -2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-2k}}{k!}$ and how can i conclude that it's true also for z?

Comment: It's true also for z using analytic continuation

Answer (score 0):

By the assumption, $A(z)$ is an analytic function in the circle $|z|<R$. Along the line segment connecting $0$ to $R$, it coincides with $e^x-2e^{-2x}$. The latter function is an entire function, in particular it is analytic in $|z|<R$. Thus, by the uniqueness properties of analytic functions, $A(z)=e^z-2e^{-2z}$ on $|z|<R$. But since $e^z-2e^{-2z}$ is entire, its Taylor series at the origin converges for all $|z|$. The original power series defining $A(z)$ must be the Taylor series of the function at the origin, so its radius of convergence $R$ is infinity. Also $A(\pi i) = e^{\pi i}  - 2e^{ - 2\pi i}  =  - 1 - 2 =  - 3$.